# Referenciar coleções no mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Tenho um modelo de um aeroporto no mysql e pretendo carrega-lo para o mongodb através de ligações entre coleções. Nas imagens seguintes são exemplos de documentos das minhas coleções. (airplane, airport and flight)

[image: flight]

[image: Airport]

[image: Airplane]

O id no flight é o id_voo, no airplane é o tailnum e no airport é idAirport. No mysql as relações são de 1:M de airplane para flight e de 1:M de flight para aeroporto. Eu exportei estes dados com as chaves estrangeiras e quero referencia-las entre documentos no mongodb. O mongo db atribui logo um objectid como principal e não era isso que pretendia. Como posso definir isto?

Comment: Isso é, você está pretendendo fazer um *join* com mongo?

Comment: Sim tipo isso. queria uma maneira de fazer uma querie que me retornasse o year de um aviao mas que onde o campo diverted fosse igual a 1. só que este campo diverted está na coleção flight

Comment: Então cara, sinto muito te dizer mas mongo não possui recursos para fazer *joins*. O paradigma é outro. Veja a resposta do sergiopereira.

Answer (score 2):

Como você sabe, o MongoDB não é relacional, portanto não há como definir uma *relação nativa* entre dois documentos. Você tem [duas alternativas](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/) mais comuns em Mongo:

1. Documentos embutidos (aninhados)
2. Referência manual, usando `_id`

Eu recomendo você ler um pouco sobre esse tópico pois é meio longo para explicar aqui no site. Cada qual tem suas vantagens e desvantagens.

Em relação à chave primária, em MongoDB esta é sempre o atributo `_id` e é imutável. Você tem que ou passar a usar `_id` em seus programas, colocando você mesmo o valor de `_id` na hora da inserção, caso contrário Mongo vai gerar um para você. O `_id` não precisa ser um valor simples, pode ser um sub-documento também, como `"_id": {"numero": 123, "apartamento": "25-B"}`.

Comment: então se no Json que eu pretendo inserir o nome estiver como _id ele insere-o automaticamente com id principal do documento? Em relação à referencia manual já pesquisei sobre isso e a minha dúvida é se basta carregar o json com as chaves estrangeiras que correspondem ás chaves primárias das tabelas mas sem haver nenhum tipo de relação é so para os id's corresponderem no mongodb?

Comment: Com relação aos `_id`s, correto. Para as FKs basta você adicionar os campos com os valores corretos. Seus exemplos parecem corretos.

Comment: Caso eu opte por documentos embutidos, por exemplo já tenho a coleção airplane criada e quero embutir dentro desta a coleção flight mas onde os tailnum são iguais, como faço para criar um documento assim?

Comment: Você vai precisar repetir os dados, tipo `_id: 4, airplane: {tailnum: "N308UA", model: "737-3TO", ..etc..  } }`. Basicamente o `airplane` passa a ser embutido no vôo, o que causará duplicação de dados. Em alguns casos isso é aceitável, em outros não, vai depender de sua análise e conhecimento do domínio do problema.

Comment: Exato por isso é que pensei na referenciação que assim não havia duplicação. A minha confusão é mesmo ter de efetuar 2 consultas. Qual o seu conselho para uma situação destas?

Comment: Não há mágica, infelizmente. Você vai precisar ou duplicar dados ou fazer mais de uma consulta para buscar os dados relacionados.

Comment: A propósito. Você tem algum motivo importante para armazenar esses dados em NoSQL? Os dados parecem típicos de bancos relacionais.

Comment: sim é um trabalho que estou a fazer comparando o mysql com o mongodb, estes dados ja veem do mysql, simplesmente importei os em json, agora estou a ver qual é o tipo de armazenamento que me da melhor performance se o embutido ou o referenciado. Tem alguma ideia de qual compensará mais em performance neste caso?